# At which point does MySQL start treating VARCHAR cols like TEXT cols?

Tags: mysql, database, text, varchar

I'm aware that since MySQL 5, `VARCHAR` can have a length of up to 65,000. VARCHAR is stored inline, which means faster retrievals, as opposed to `TEXT`, which is stored outside of the table. That said, the documentation states that MySQL will treat `LONG VARCHAR` exactly `TEXT`.

According to [this Source](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/):

> From storage prospective BLOB, TEXT as
>   well as long VARCHAR are handled same
>   way by Innodb. This is why Innodb
>   manual calls it “long columns” rather
>   than BLOBs.

When does MySQL start treating VARCHAR like TEXT? At what character count does MySQL make this distinction, and VARCHAR stops getting stored inline?

Comment: At a guess, I would imagine it would be when `VARCHAR` moves to the long format, which would be after it goes beyond the older limit, which was 255 characters I believe - check the old limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: A "long" VARCHAR is a normal VARCHAR and will be inline.

MySQL won't magically start treating a straight VARCHAR as a text type. It'll always be stored inline. With 5.0.3, the upper limit for VARCHARs was relaxed to 65,535 bytes. They also take up 2 bytes of header if over 255 characters. This limit is still applied to the maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. A LONG VARCHAR is actually a different type which backcompats to MEDIUMTEXT.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html